# Como ejecutar dos sentencias con un mismo href""

Tags: html, href

Buenas tardes compañeros. Es mi primer duda expuesta en este foro, disculpen si ya hay una respuesta previa de esto, busqué pero no encontré algo tal y como lo necesito. Explico:

Tengo una pagina en la cual desde un iframe se integró un video de youtube y en la parte de abajo, hay muchos videos elegibles desde los cuales, al darles clic, "manda" el video hacia el iframe del inicio. Como son muchos videos en la lista de abajo, me gustaría que al darle clic a esas opciones, también me mandara automáticamente hacia arriba. Puedo hacer que me mande hacia arriba si utilizo un <href="#"> el detalle esta en que en la lista de videos de la parte inferior, ya utilizo un href para enviar el código hacia el iframe, de ahi mi duda si es posible utilizar dos sentencias de href en una sola opción?

Este es el código base:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video1"></iframe>
<section id="escoger">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video2" target="iframe1"><h4>Video2</h4></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video3" target="iframe1"><h4>Video3</h4></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video4" target="iframe1"><h4>Video4</h4></a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video(...N)" target="iframe1"><h4>Video(...N)</h4></a>
</section>
```

Esta es la duda que tengo:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video2" + href="#" target="iframe1"><h4>Video2</h4></a>
```

Se que no es de esta forma, es solo para dar la idea de que es lo que me gustaría que hiciera. agradeceré de antemano cualquier orientación al respecto.

Comment: lo que estas preguntando no se hace con html se hace con javascript debes aprender a manejar eventos con javascript y luego como hacer peticiones get y post... a las URL, que seria lo mismo que un href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `onclick` para ejecutar una función que lleve al usuario a la parte superior de la página al hacer click sobre el link, así:

```js
function goUp(){
  scroll(0,0);
}
```

```html
<iframe name="iframe1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video1"></iframe>
<section id="escoger">
  <a  onclick='goUp()'href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video2" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video2</h4>
  </a>
  <a onclick='goUp()' href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video3" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video3</h4>
  </a>
  <a onclick='goUp()' href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video4" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video4</h4>
  </a>
  <a onclick='goUp()' href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video(...N)" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video(...N)</h4>
  </a>
</section>
```

Si la lista es muy larga podrías entonces agregar el atributo de `onclick` a todos los hijos de `.section` de una manera más automatizaad, para no pasar repitiendo código, así:

```js
function goUp() {
  scroll(0, 0);
}

document.getElementById('escoger').childNodes.forEach(function(child) {
  child.onclick = goUp
});
```

```html
<iframe name="iframe1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video1"></iframe>
<section id="escoger">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video2" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video2</h4>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video3" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video3</h4>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video4" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video4</h4>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video(...N)" target="iframe1">
    <h4>Video(...N)</h4>
  </a>
</section>
```

Update:

```
    <iframe name="iframe1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video1"></iframe>
    <section id="escoger">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video2" target="iframe1">
        <h4>Video2</h4>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video3" target="iframe1">
        <h4>Video3</h4>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video4" target="iframe1">
        <h4>Video4</h4>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/video(...N)" target="iframe1">
        <h4>Video(...N)</h4>
      </a>
    </section>
<script>
function goUp() {
      scroll(0, 0);
    }

    document.getElementById('escoger').childNodes.forEach(function(child) {
      child.onclick = goUp
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes agrégarlio como un script  de javascript al final del cuerpo de tu html, usando `<script>function goUp().....=goUp});<\script>`

Comment: Perdón, borre el comentario y no me di cuenta que habías escrito. Tu respuesta me ha funcionado de mil maravillas. Si hay forma de como calificarte o alguna acción que te ayude por favor hazmelo saber, acabo de ingresar al foro y no se como funciona en su totalidad. Te agradezco mucho tu apoyo, en apariencia son cosas muy sencillas pero valoro mucho a las personas que se tomas el tiempo de ayudar a quienes estamos en el camino del aprendizaje. Gracias...

Comment: Con marcar la pregunta cómo respuesta es suficiente, es un gusto ayudar a la comunidad. Todo siempre parece sencillo al inicio.

Comment: Puedes dar una breve lectura a esta página para aprender sobre como usar este foro: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour